# Different colours edges in graphviz in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, graphviz

I am trying to draw graph with different colours edges by using graphviz in Python. I am creating colour list and using in edge colour. However, it looks like it does not support in graphviz. I am not sure how to set different colour of edges. Here is my code:

```
import graphviz as gv

d = gv.Digraph()
colors = ['green','red']
d.attr('edge', color = colors)
d.edge('hello','world')
d.edge('world','hello')
d.view()
```

Looking for valuable comments. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

```
import graphviz as gv

colors = ['green','red']


def create_graph(colors, d):

  d.edge('hello','world', color=colors[0])
  d.edge('world','hello', color=colors[1])
  d.view()

if __name__ == '__main__':

  d = gv.Digraph()

  create_graph(colors, d)
```

Comment: I hop this is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really know the python wrapper for graphviz,but if by *different colour of edges* you mean *multiple* colors (?), you may try the following:

```
d.attr('edge', color = 'green:red')
```

Otherwise, if you'd like to have a green and a red edge, the following may work:

```
d.edge('hello','world', color='green' )
d.edge('world','hello', color='red' )
```